# Why is this C++ fold expression valid?

Tags: c++, syntax, fold-expression

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), I saw that there are four types of fold expressions, unary right, unary left, binary right, and binary left. What is the type of this fold expression here? I'm having a hard time understanding why it is valid.

```
    template <typename Res, typename... Ts>
    vector<Res> to_vector(Ts&&... ts) {
        vector<Res> vec;
        (vec.push_back(ts) ...); // *
        return vec;
    }
```

What is the value of "pack", "op" and "init" in line *, if any?

This example is from page 244 of Bjarne Stroustrup's [*A Tour of C++*](http://www.stroustrup.com/tour2.html) book, and seems like a comma was forgotten in the example, hence my confusion.

Comment: you end up with bunch of `vec.push_back(...)`s separated by comma?

Comment: Yes, that I understand. I want to know how the line fits into the definition of a valid fold expression.

Comment: You can check [this errata](http://www.stroustrup.com/tour2_errata.html), then you will see that this book has many other errors, why not report this as typo - `,` is missing ?

Comment: @rafix07 I wouldn't call 10 errors in about 200 pages "many"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax is not valid. It's missing a comma (most likely a typo):

```
(vec.push_back(ts), ...)
//                ^
```

And so it is "unary right fold":

```
( pack op ... )
```

with `op` being a comma.

Comment: Note that when expanding a pack while calling a function, `(pack...)` is right, when folding `(pack,...)` is right.  I get burned by this pretty often myself.